# How to remove white-space between nested border?

Tags: css, windows, google-chrome

I try to create element with nested border like the following image. But there are some white-space between these 2 containers without no reason.

I can reproduce this issue on Chrome and Edge.

[image]

**HTML**

```
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 5px solid blue;
}

#container2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  border: 5px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#bar {
  background: orange;
  height: 24px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cjg9zf1o/9/

**Thanks,**

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue. What version of Chrome are you using? What resolution? Either way, you can almost definitely solve this with `* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }`.

Comment: Reset padding & margin don't change anything. I test this on my machine (Win10 + Chrome 65 + Main monitor with 125% dpi)

Comment: I also can reproduce this issue on my remote machine (Win Server 2012 + Chrome)

Comment: It seems to be DPI-related issue. I cannot reproduce with 100% dpi monitor.

Comment: I can reproduce it only when zooming in.